# Upgraded server to 12.04 DNS no longer working

Tags: dns, home-server

I cannot ping/reach any website/service by name (e.g. ping google.com).

I could temporarily fix this by changing 127.0.0.1 to my router in /etc/resolv.conf
But that file gets overwritten.

How can I permanently fix this?

To be clear, I don't need a DNS server, I just want my server to be able to use DNS from DHCP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it in another way, because I have the impression the solution above is doing what was not asked, i.e. implementing a dhcp server.

I deleted the bind9 and dhcp3-server with

```
sudo aptitude remove bind9 dhcp3-server
```

and restarted networking with

```
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

I also changed the file /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf. Its contents looks like:

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=true
```

After modifying this file, I had to restart the Network Manager service:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Now the dhcp client seems to set the dns server to the one provided by dhcp.

Answer (score 6):

**Setup Static DNS Servers in Ubuntu 12.04 (Precise Pangolin)**

```
sudo nano /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf
```

Then change the line highlighted to

```
prepend domain-name-servers x.x.x.x, y.y.y.y;
```

[image]

[liberiangeek](http://www.liberiangeek.net/2012/05/setup-static-dns-servers-in-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin/)

---

Ubuntu 12.04 changes the way DNS setup is handled. Rather than adding nameservers to /etc/resolv.conf, they need to be added to /etc/network/interfaces.

Edit **/etc/network/interfaces**, look for your primary ethernet device **(such as eth0)**, and add this line under your primary ethernet device:

```
dns-nameservers 127.0.0.1
```

And then restart your networking:

```
/etc/init.d/networking restart
```

[virtualmin](http://www.virtualmin.com/book/export/html/22006)

Comment: Note that this also breaks Vagrant and you need to add this line in your config: config.vm.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnshostresolver1", "on"]